# Set default country code in amplify authenticator signup component

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

Amplify authenticator is really convenient for common authentication flow.

By default, the country code is pre-select to +1, but the apps developed for other countries may want to default to another one.

Is there a way to change the default pre-selected value.

[The official document](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#sign-up) doesn't include anything about this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

signUpConfig.defaultCountryCode to the rescure.

After reading the source code of amplify-js. Here the code is.

```
getDefaultDialCode() {
        return this.props.signUpConfig &&
            this.props.signUpConfig.defaultCountryCode &&
            countryDialCodes.indexOf(
                `+${this.props.signUpConfig.defaultCountryCode}`
            ) !== -1
            ? `+${this.props.signUpConfig.defaultCountryCode}`
            : '+1';
    }
```

So to use it. The HOC should like

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, {signUpConfig: {defaultCountryCode: 61}})
```

Comment: However `signUpConfig` no longer exists when using `withAuthenticator` from the new UI package `@aws-amplify/ui-react`, which seems to be the successor of `aws-amplify-react`. The doc for `@aws-amplify/ui-react` does mention [migration](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#migration) for `withAuthenticator`, but the doc eventually has no info on setting default phone country code... not even sure if there's an option for this in the new UI package.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `dialCode` in formFields.

```
{
  type: 'phone_number',
  dialCode: 27, // or '+27' 
  value: '5555555555',
}
```

Comment: const formFields: AuthFormFields = {
  signUp: {
    phone_number: {
      dialCode: '+91',
    },
  },
};
accordingt to latest docs